# My Google Chrome remove cookies after I Close browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, cookies

Every time I turn off the system or the browser closes, I have to login to all sites again. I was skeptical of only one option, but the problem did not go away. please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO6Tr.png)

Comment: Uninstall Chrome completely including ALL extensions. Restart. Install Chrome and set up normally (not incognito) and see if sites save. Works fine here.

Comment: There's plenty of good results searching this question online, so what research have you done and what have you tried?